# How to change a view field programatically

Tags: views

I want to change the result of a view field in a custom module.I’m not sure which of the hooks to use for this there are not a lot of examples of how to use the views hooks for d8

Comment: better to look at how to create custom twig extensions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PeAfExNSDk

Comment: you can use ```custom_module_views_pre_view($view, $display_id, array &$args) ``` hook. I update my answer below

Answer (score -4):

You can user the [Views PHP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/php)

You add your php logic to the field and manipulate the view field results as you wish.

If you really need to use a hook in your custom module you can use the

`custom_module_views_pre_view($view, $display_id, array &$args)` hook